# How do I convert three lists into one dictionary?

Tags: python

I have an inventory program that stores the ID number, item name, and the quantity in three different lists. These three lists are combined in an inventory list but, when the data is saves to a TextEdit document it stores the data in three different lists. How do I save this data in one dictionary. First ID number, item name, then qty.

Here is the full program code:

```
import os

class Inventory:
    def __init__(self):
    #AT LAUNCH GROUPS AND LOADING FUNCTION
        self.ID = []
        self.item = []
        self.qty = []
        self.load()

    def remove(self, ID):
        #REMOVING ITEMS FOR LISTS AND OUTPUT DOCUMENT
        ix = self.ID.index(ID)
        self.ID.pop(ix)
        self.item.pop(ix)
        self.qty.pop(ix)
        self.save()

    def add(self, ID, name, qty):
        #ADDING ITEMS FOR LISTS AND OUTPUT DOCUMENT
        self.ID.append(ID)
        self.item.append(name)
        self.qty.append(qty)
        self.save()

    def update(self, ID, update):
        #UPDATING ITEMS FOR LISTS AND OUTPUT DOCUMENT
        if update >= 0:
            self.qty[self.ID.index(ID)] += update
        elif update <= -1:
            self.qty[self.ID.index(ID)] += update
        self.save()

    def search(self, ID):
        #SEARCHING ITEMS FOR LISTS
        pos = self.ID.index(ID) if ID in self.ID else -1
        if pos >= 0:
            return self.ID[pos], self.item[pos], self.qty[pos] 
        else:
            return None

    def __str__(self):
        #FORMATTING
        out = ""
        zipo = list(zip(self.ID, self.item, self.qty))
        for foobar in zipo:
            out += f"ID Number : {foobar[0]} \nItem Name : {foobar[1]}\nQuantity : {foobar[2]}\n"
            out += "----------\n"
        return out
    
    def save(self):
        #WHERE TO SAVE TO
        with open('inventory.dat','w') as f:
           f.write(str(self.ID) + '\n' + str(self.item) + '\n' + str(self.qty))

    def load(self):
        #WHERE TO PUT DATA FROM WHEN RELAUNCHING PROGRAM
        from os import path
        if path.exists('inventory.dat'):
            with open('inventory.dat','r') as f:
               lns = f.readlines()
               self.ID = eval(lns[0])
               self.item = eval(lns[1])
               self.qty = eval(lns[2])



def menuDisplay():
    #MENU FOR PROGRAM 
    """Display the menu"""
    print('=============================')
    print('= Inventory Management Menu =')
    print('=============================')
    print('(1) Add New Item to Inventory')
    print('(2) Remove Item from Inventory')
    print('(3) Update Inventory')
    print('(4) Search Item in Inventory')
    print('(5) Print Inventory Report')
    print('(99) Quit')


def add_one_item(inventory):
    #ADDING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Adding Inventory')
    print('================')
    while True:
        try:
            new_ID = int(input("Enter an ID number for the item: "))
            if new_ID in inventory.ID:
                print("ID number is taken, please enter a different ID number")
                continue
            new_name = input('Enter the name of the item: ').lower()
            assert new_name.isalpha(), "Only letters are allowed!"
            new_qty = int(input("Enter the quantity of the item: "))
            inventory.add(new_ID, new_name, new_qty)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again! " + str(e))
            print()


def remove_one_item(inventory):
    #REMOVING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Removing Inventory')
    print('==================')
    removing = int(input("Enter the item's ID number to remove from inventory: "))
    inventory.remove(removing)


def ask_exit_or_continue():
    #OPTION TO CONTINUE OR QUITE PROGRAM
    return int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))


def update_inventory(inventory):
    #UPDATING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Updating Inventory')
    print('==================')
    ID = int(input("Enter the item's ID number to update: "))
    update = int(input("Enter the updated quantity. Enter 5 for additional or -5 for less: "))
    inventory.update(ID, update)


def search_inventory(inventory):
    #SEARCHING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Searching Inventory')
    print('===================')
    search = int(input("Enter the ID number of the item: "))
    result = inventory.search(search)
    if result is None:
        print("Item not in inventory")
    else:
        ID, name, qty = result
        print('ID Number: ', ID)
        print('Item:     ', name)
        print('Quantity: ', qty)
        print('----------')


def print_inventory(inventory):
    #PRINT CURRENT LIST OF ITEMS IN INVENTORY
    print('Current Inventory')
    print('=================')
    print(inventory)


def main():
    #PROGRAM RUNNING COMMAND AND ERROR CHECKING
    inventory = Inventory()
    while True:
        try:
            menuDisplay()
            CHOICE = int(input("Enter choice: "))
            if CHOICE in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
                if CHOICE == 1:
                    add_one_item(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 2:
                    remove_one_item(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 3:
                    update_inventory(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 4:
                    search_inventory(inventory)
                elif CHOICE == 5:
                    print_inventory(inventory)
                exit_choice = ask_exit_or_continue()
                if exit_choice == 99:
                    exit()
            elif CHOICE == 99:
                exit()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again!"+str(e))
            print()

        # If the user pick an invalid choice,
        # the program will come to here and
        # then loop back.


main()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you put them in 3 lists in the first place?

Comment: Everything would be simpler if you just had a list of dictionaries instead of 3 different lists.

Comment: I thought it would be easier. I was wrong. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Or a single dictionary whose keys are the IDs and the values are dictionaries with item and quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use 3 lists, use a dictionary containing dictionaries. The keys of the main dictionary will be the IDs, and the values will be dictionaries containing the name and quantity.

You can use JSON or pickle to save and load the data.

```
import os
import json

class Inventory:
    def __init__(self):
        #AT LAUNCH GROUPS AND LOADING FUNCTION
        self.items = {}
        self.load()

    def remove(self, ID):
        #REMOVING ITEMS FOR LISTS AND OUTPUT DOCUMENT
        del self.items[ID]
        self.save()

    def add(self, ID, name, qty):
        #ADDING ITEMS FOR LISTS AND OUTPUT DOCUMENT
        self.items[ID] = {"name": name, "qty": qty}
        self.save()

    def update(self, ID, update):
        #UPDATING ITEMS FOR LISTS AND OUTPUT DOCUMENT
        self.items[ID]["qty"] += update
        self.save()

    def search(self, ID):
        #SEARCHING ITEMS FOR LISTS
        item = self.items.get(ID, None)
        if item:
            return ID, item['name'], item['qty']
        else:
            return None

    def __str__(self):
        #FORMATTING
        out = ""
        for id, d in self.items.items():
            out += f"ID Number : {id} \nItem Name : {d['name']}\nQuantity : {d['qty']}\n"
            out += "----------\n"
        return out
    
    def save(self):
        #WHERE TO SAVE TO
        with open('inventory.dat','w') as f:
           json.dump(self.items, f)

    def load(self):
        #WHERE TO PUT DATA FROM WHEN RELAUNCHING PROGRAM
        try:
            with open('inventory.dat','r') as f:
               self.items = json.load(f)
        except:
            print("Can't load old inventory, starting fresh")
            self.items = {}
```

You should avoid accessing attributes directly outside the class, as it makes it difficult to reimplement the class so

```
if new_ID in inventory.ID:
```

should be

```
if inventory.search(new_ID):
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224513/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-how-do-i-convert-three-lists-into-one-dictionary).